# Random number between two numbers with "gaps"

Tags: vba, random

I am trying to generate random numbers between two values.
I am using, vba for this, so that, the way to do It would be:

```
Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
```

But because of the particular situation I am in, I need to exclude numbers from the middle of the sequence, so for example I need numbers between 50 and 100 and I need to exclude 80, 50, and 77, for example

So to do this, I wrap the random number generator in a Do While loop, and check if the number is one of the excluded numbers, and if it is, I keep generating numbers.

This brute-force seems to me inefficient and I am not sure about the statistical properties of the sequence if I do this,

are there more elegant algorithms to accomplish this task?

thanks in advance

Comment: One idea:  if you had a list of valid numbers, you could use Rnd as an index into that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a list of valid numbers, you could use Rnd as an index into that list.  In your example, the list would have 48 items.  I use the number of items as the seed for Rnd:

```
Option Explicit

Private nums As Collection

Private Sub Form_Load()
   'build your list however you need
   Set nums = BuildList(50, 100, 50, 77, 80)
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim i As Integer
   
   i = Int((nums.Count * Rnd) + 1)
   Debug.Print nums(i)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

### Generate Random Numbers With Exclusions

**Usage**

```vb
Sub Usage()

    Dim WereNumbersPrinted As Boolean
    WereNumbersPrinted = PrintRandomIntegerSequence( _
        50, 100, 5, Array(50, 80, 77), True)
    Debug.Print "Were numbers printed? Result = " & WereNumbersPrinted & vbLf

End Sub
```

**Method As Function**

```vb
' This is a sub written as a function to return a boolean indicating
' whether it was successful.
Function PrintRandomIntegerSequence( _
        ByVal FirstInteger As Long, _
        ByVal SecondInteger As Long, _
        ByVal SampleSize As Long, _
        Optional ByVal Exclusions As Variant = Empty, _
        Optional ByVal ShowMessage As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Print Random Integer Sequence"
    Const MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE As Long = 200 ' max number of rows...
                                        ' ... in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If SampleSize < 1 Or SampleSize > MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE Then
        If ShowMessage Then ' 1st
            MsgBox "The sample size has to be an integer between 1 and " _
                & MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE & "! It cannot be " & SampleSize & "!", _
                vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim IsExcluding As Boolean: IsExcluding = IsArray(Exclusions)
    
    Dim iCount As Long: iCount = Abs(SecondInteger - FirstInteger) + 1
    If iCount = 1 Then
        If ShowMessage Then ' 2nd
            MsgBox "The first (" & FirstInteger & ") and second integer (" _
                & SecondInteger & ") cannot be the same!", _
                vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Determine the minimum and maximum.
    
    Dim NumMin As Long, NumMax As Long
    
    NumMin = IIf(FirstInteger < SecondInteger, FirstInteger, SecondInteger)
    NumMax = IIf(FirstInteger < SecondInteger, SecondInteger, FirstInteger)
    
    ' Return the integers in a 1D array.
    
    Dim Arr() As Long: ReDim Arr(1 To iCount)
    Dim CurrentInteger As Long: CurrentInteger = NumMin
    
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, IsMatch As Boolean
    
    ' Loop.
    For i = 1 To iCount
        If IsExcluding Then
            If IsNumeric(Application.Match(CurrentInteger, Exclusions, 0)) Then
                IsMatch = True
            End If
        End If
        If IsMatch Then ' excluding
            IsMatch = False
        Else ' including
            n = n + 1
            Arr(n) = CurrentInteger
        End If
        CurrentInteger = CurrentInteger + 1
    Next i
       
    ' Check.
    If n = 0 Then
        If ShowMessage Then ' 3rd
            MsgBox "All numbers were found in the exclusions list.", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
       
    ' Resize.
    If IsExcluding Then
        If n < iCount Then
            ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To n)
        End If
    End If

    ' Print.
    
    If n > 0 Then Debug.Print "Index", "Number"
    
    For i = 1 To SampleSize
        Debug.Print i, Arr(Int(n * Rnd + 1)) ' Int((n - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Next i
    
    ' Assign the result to the function.
    
    PrintRandomIntegerSequence = True
    
    If ShowMessage Then ' 4th
        MsgBox "Random numbers returned in the Immediate window ('Ctrl+G').", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    If ShowMessage Then ' 5th
        MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Test**

```vb
Sub Test()
    
    Dim Exclusions() As Variant: Exclusions = Array(50, 80, 77)
    
    Dim WereNumbersPrinted As Boolean
    
    ' OK
    
    Debug.Print "Has Exclusions - No Message"
    WereNumbersPrinted = PrintRandomIntegerSequence( _
        50, 100, 5, Exclusions)
    Debug.Print "Were numbers printed? Result = " & WereNumbersPrinted & vbLf

    Debug.Print "No Exclusions - 4th Message - 1st > 2nd"
    WereNumbersPrinted = PrintRandomIntegerSequence(5, 1, 5, , True)
    Debug.Print "Were numbers printed? Result = " & WereNumbersPrinted & vbLf
    
    Debug.Print "No Exclusions (Invalid) - 4th Message - Ignore Exclusions"
    WereNumbersPrinted = PrintRandomIntegerSequence(50, 100, 5, "Nope", True)
    Debug.Print "Were numbers printed? Result = " & WereNumbersPrinted & vbLf

    ' Not OK
    
    Debug.Print "No Exclusions - 1st Message - Invalid Sample Size (<)"
    WereNumbersPrinted = PrintRandomIntegerSequence(50, 50, 0, , True)
    Debug.Print "Were numbers printed? Result = " & WereNumbersPrinted & vbLf

    Debug.Print "No Exclusions - 1st Message - Invalid Sample Size (>)"
    WereNumbersPrinted = PrintRandomIntegerSequence(50, 100, 201, , True)
    Debug.Print "Were numbers printed? Result = " & WereNumbersPrinted & vbLf

    Debug.Print "No Exclusions - 2nd Message - 1st = 2nd"
    WereNumbersPrinted = PrintRandomIntegerSequence(1, 1, 5, , True)
    Debug.Print "Were numbers printed? Result = " & WereNumbersPrinted & vbLf

    Debug.Print "Has Exclusions (Different) - 3rd Message - All Numbers in List"
    WereNumbersPrinted = PrintRandomIntegerSequence(3, 4, 1, Array(3, 4), True)
    Debug.Print "Were numbers printed? Result = " & WereNumbersPrinted & vbLf

    Debug.Print "Has Exclusions - 5th Message - e.g. Empty Array (Error)"
    WereNumbersPrinted = PrintRandomIntegerSequence( _
        50, 100, 5, Array(), True)
    Debug.Print "Were numbers printed? Result = " & WereNumbersPrinted & vbLf

End Sub
```

**Test Result Example**

```
Has Exclusions - No Message
Index         Number
 1             64 
 2             70 
 3             78 
 4             65 
 5             65 
Were numbers printed? Result = True

No Exclusions - 4th Message - 1st > 2nd
Index         Number
 1             5 
 2             2 
 3             2 
 4             3 
 5             5 
Were numbers printed? Result = True

No Exclusions (Invalid) - 4th Message - Ignore Exclusions
Index         Number
 1             70 
 2             86 
 3             83 
 4             70 
 5             98 
Were numbers printed? Result = True

No Exclusions - 1st Message - Invalid Sample Size (<)
Were numbers printed? Result = False

No Exclusions - 1st Message - Invalid Sample Size (>)
Were numbers printed? Result = False

No Exclusions - 2nd Message - 1st = 2nd
Were numbers printed? Result = False

Has Exclusions (Different) - 3rd Message - All Numbers in List
Were numbers printed? Result = False

Has Exclusions - 5th Message - e.g. Empty Array (Error)
Were numbers printed? Result = False
```